# Users not logged in since new year

Tags: sql-server-2008, jira

I am trying to write a SQL query which will return the users who haven't logged in since new year. Here is the query.

```
SELECT 
    [jira].[dbo].[cwd_user].user_name,
    dateadd(second,cast(cast([jira].[dbo].[cwd_user_attributes].attribute_value as nvarchar(255)) as bigint)/1000,'19700101 00:00:00:000') AS last_logged
FROM 
    [jira].[dbo].[cwd_user], [jira].[dbo].[cwd_user_attributes]
WHERE 
    [jira].[dbo].[cwd_user].id = [jira].[dbo].[cwd_user_attributes].user_id
    AND [jira].[dbo].[cwd_user_attributes].attribute_name = 'login.lastLoginMillis'
    AND [jira].[dbo].[cwd_user_attributes].attribute_value < DATEPART(MS, '2012-12-31 23:59:59')
```

I am getting following error.

> The conversion of the nvarchar value '1374247985584' overflowed an int column.

Comment: Well the message is correct 1374247985584 is too big to fit in an integer. What is the format of the attribute_value column originally? Also are you ware that DATEPART(MS, xxx) returns only the millisecond part of the date which I guess for the date you entered would be 0?

Comment: @DaveWilliams, the format of the attribute_value column is nvarchar(255).

Comment: Why store it as nvarchar? If its a date store it as a date if its ticks store it as bigint etc.. What are you actually storing there?

Comment: @DaveWilliams, it is the JIRA database where the time of last login is recorded.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Right well I didn't know what that was until just now and you didn't say that in the question! I suggest you ask question on the Atlassian forums or whatever. For now I can tell you the problem is with the last line which is trying to compare nvarchar to int (milliseconds) if you want to do the comparison you need to convert one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the last login is stored as Unix time time so you need to convert the time at 31-12-2012 to Unix time for the comparison.

The Unix time includes milliseconds in this case so you also need to multiply by 1000 or add 999 to the end e.g.

Attribute_value < '1357019999999'

Or

```
attribute_value < DATEDIFF(ms,'19700101 00:00:00:000','20121231 23:59:59:999')
```

You can put in whichever time stamp you like and it should be able to compare the two nvarchars correctly.

Comment: The table cwd_user_attributes stores the info in a key pair format. So, for key login.lastLoginMillis, the value is 1374247985584.

Comment: Yes I can see that... But the value part of the pair is an nvarchar which represents the milliseconds elapsed since 1970 so you need to compare that with the same thing for your new year date. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one is for Oracle (sorry, no SQL Server at hands), lists users and activity timestamp if its in or after 2013.

```
WITH w_all_user_activities AS
 (SELECT author, g.created 
  FROM jiraissue i
  INNER JOIN changegroup g ON i.id = g.issueid
  INNER JOIN changeitem c ON c.groupid = g.id
  UNION
  SELECT author, created FROM jiraaction
  UNION
  SELECT reporter, created FROM jiraissue),
w_tmp_latest_user_activities AS
 (SELECT author, created, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY author ORDER BY created DESC) dest_rank
  FROM w_all_user_activities ),
w_latest_user_activities AS
 (SELECT author, created FROM w_tmp_latest_user_activities WHERE dest_rank = 1)
SELECT * 
FROM w_latest_user_activities 
WHERE created >= TO_DATE('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Then you might do an antijoin against `cwd_user` to get the passive users.